# How to add uncheck to last element in ngRepeat Check-Boxex using Angular js?

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, checkbox

I am using Check-box model as seen here http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/ for check boxes with Angularjs.  Some of the Check-boxes need the last check-box element to uncheck all the others.  How would I add a ngClick attribute to the last element in a set of Checkboxes using the check-box-model module.

Comment: use $last to check last element in ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Solution:

**<kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebv3p/7/)</kbd>**

```
 <label ng-repeat="role in roles">
    <input ng-click="$last&&mytest()" type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.id"> {{role.text}}
  </label>
```

Click on last check box "admin" and it will be alert box

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know much about checklist-model but you can add ngClick to the last element like this:

```
<label ng-click={{$last && yourFunction || ''}} ng-repeat="role in roles">
  <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role"> {{role}}
</label>
```

Though, It will add `ng-click` attribute to all elements but this can work for you. Its an alternative.